# Testing trends in proportions with R: prop.trend.test vs rstatix::prop_trend_test

Tags: r, proportion, ordinal-data, count-data

I have an ordinal variable (disease severity index, scores = 0, 1, 2, 3) and presence/absence counts (number of people with presence/absence of virus). I am testing whether or not incidence of the virus increases with disease severity.

It seems that a trend for test in proportions is appropriate here. There is a base R option (prop.trend.test), and an rstatix option (prop_trend_test, which wraps prop.trend.test).

I expected both of these tests to give the same result, but the p-value varies quite a bit between the two. This is also true for the example data provided in the prop_trend_test readme.

Setting up the data:

```
# Data
xtab <- as.table(rbind(
  c(384, 536, 335),
  c(951, 869, 438)
))
dimnames(xtab) <- list(
  stone = c("yes", "no"),
  age = c("30-39", "40-49", "50-59")
)

### Prep for prop.trend.test
yes <- as.numeric(xtab[1,1:3])
no <- as.numeric(xtab[2,1:3])
```

Output:

```
> rstatix::prop_trend_test(xtab)
# A tibble: 1 × 6
      n statistic        p p.signif    df method               
* <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>                
1  3513      49.7 1.78e-12 ****         1 Chi-square trend test

> prop.trend.test(yes, no)

    Chi-squared Test for Trend in Proportions

data:  yes out of no ,
 using scores: 1 2 3
X-squared = 177.48, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my understanding of the statistical test I am applying or the coding involved, but I have to assume I have gone wrong somewhere here and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Read the output of `prop.trend.test(yes, no)` carefully; it's very helpful as it says "data:  yes out of no". Naturally you want `prop.trend.test(yes, yes + no)` instead. Then the two functions return the same statisic and p-value.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me from making a very unfortunate mistake

Comment: Well done to try alternative implementations of the same theory. It's always good to read the documentation. You can do this with `?prop.trend.test`.